# In pandas, how to convert the result of dividing two columns from a decimal to a percentage?

Tags: python, pandas

When using pandas, how do I convert a decimal to a percentage when the result obtained by dividing two columns as another column?

for example :

```
df_income_structure['C'] = (df_income_structure['A']/df_income_structure['B'])
```

If the value of df_income_structure['C'] is a decimal, how to convert it to a percentage ?

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput?

Answer (score 3):

Format it like this:

```
df_income_structure.style.format({'C': '{:,.2%}'.format})
```

Change the number depending on how many decimal places you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Use basic pandas operators
For example if we have a dataframe with columns name like `column1, column2,column3 , ...` so we can :

Columns = [column1, column2,column3, ....] .

```
df[Columns] = df[Columns].div(df[Columns].sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100)
```

1. (df[Columns].sum(axis=1). axis=1 makes the summation for rows.
2. Divide the dataframe by (df[Columns].div(df[Columns].sum(axis=1), axis=0). axis=0 is for devision of columns.
3. multiply the results by 100 for percentages of 100.

I hope this answer has solved your problem.

Good luck